IPSEC configuration and usage on networks with overlapping network addresses
I use a different SSL VPN client to connect to remote customers. I would prefer to connect directly to remote devices in ssh and/or monitor the same ones via SNMP.
The problem is that although each customer has its own public ip,  their LAN use the same private IP addressing (10.x.x.x and 172.x.x.x).
Should it be possible to create an IPSec VPN to manage all the devices for all the customers?
How can I implement this solution?
The aim is to simplify management and eliminate the need to use many SSL VPN clients, and thus the need to establish a VPN connection to each and every customer.
My endpoint is a Cisco ASA, remote endpoints are  different vendors such as Palo Alto, Fortinet, and Checkpoint.
Posted the same question in Network Engineering but closed as off-topic.

Not sure I understand the question. but if you're trying to keep an active connection to all customers using your asa, I think you would need to set up tunnels to each endpoint.
